# Parse Error (Code: 102) shows up for some of my queries starting today (11/17/2014)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Not sure if this new addition to Parse:
http://blog.parse.com/2014/11/17/attack-of-the-clones/

Which was released today is causing this, but since today some of my queries started failing. I specifically get this:

```
Error Domain=Parse Code=102 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 102.)" UserInfo=0x78f9f170 {code=102, error=$select/dontSelect where cannot be empty}
```

Another format shows the error as follows:

```
Error: $select/dontSelect where cannot be empty (Code: 102, Version: 1.5.0)
```

The code that used to work fine:

```
PFQuery *bookingsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@“Booking”];
PFQuery *toursQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Tour"];

[bookingsQuery whereKey:@"tourId" matchesKey:@"objectId" inQuery:toursQuery];   // this line for some reason started to cause the error Today (11/17/2014)
```

I had **Parse SDK version 1.4.2**, and now updated to **1.5.0** thinking that it could help, but it did not.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Thanks in advance,
I'm running out of options.

My app is in External Beta Testing (TestFlight) now, so it's not a new project that I'm fiddling with. It was working for several months now.

Comment: Same problem here dude. I started my dev app like everyday and today i am getting the same error.

Comment: I think you might be better off contacting support than writing here.

Comment: It seems that they're aware of it:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/795944720463330/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse team were able to reproduce and are investigating the issue. It's occurring for a certain number of apps.

Here's the link for the bug:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/795944720463330/